# Best way to store a word list in Java/Android

Tags: java, android

I'm building a game where I form words (think Scrabble) and I need to have them validated in real-time, meaning that I need to have some sort of word list loaded where I can check if the word made exists or not.

I was wondering what would be the best way to store that list, should I just create an Array or use some sort of database (sqlite3 in this case).

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

One of the most space-efficient ways to store dictionary words for quick lookup is [a trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Comment: I used a trie for a [game I wrote in Actionscript 3](http://playadlib.com) with good results. My dictionary had about 80,000 words and I scanned the board for all possible words in real time. The advantage of a trie over a dictionary is better space efficiency and the ability to find all prefixed words in a string. i.e. the string "catchers" contains the words "cat", "catcher", and "catchers".

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at trie. Never heard of them to be honest.